# Hyperledger error when trying to query the state database after installing the chaincode

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

This is just an extract of my chaincod package but I use the function `ListDoctorPermissions` to query the state database after an asset, which in my case is a permission with the struct of:

```
type Permission struct {
    PermissionId    string `json:"permissionId"`
    DataCategory    string `json:"dataCategory"`
    PatientId       string `json:"patientId"`
    DoctorId        string `json:"doctorId"`
    Right           string `json:"right"`
    From            string `json:"from"`
    To              string `json:"to"`
}
```

In the process of deploying the chaincode I run the query at the end to test the chaincode but I get an error:

```
Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"Error handling success response. Value did not match schema:\n1. return: Invalid type. Expected: array, given: string"
```

This is how I invoke the chaincode:

```
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n permissions -c '{"Args":["ListDoctorPermissions", "doctor1"]}'
```

Before running the query I create a permission in the state database with the doctorId of "doctor1" so there shouldn't be a problem finding the compositeKey and entry in the database(couchDB).

```golang
// List all Permissions given to a doctor
func (s *SmartContract) ListDoctorPermissions(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, doctorId string) ([]byte, error) {
    doctorIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetStateByPartialCompositeKey("permissionId", []string{doctorId})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("the doctor Iterator is: %s", doctorIterator)

    defer doctorIterator.Close()

    var dataCategory string
    var patientId string
    var permissionId string

    var permissions []byte
    bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten := false

    for doctorIterator.HasNext() {
        responseRange, err := doctorIterator.Next()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        objectType, compositeKeyParts, err := ctx.GetStub().SplitCompositeKey(responseRange.Key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        fmt.Printf("the objectType is: %s", objectType)

        dataCategory = compositeKeyParts[1]
        patientId = compositeKeyParts[2]
        permissionId = doctorId + dataCategory + patientId
        fmt.Printf("the compositeKeyParts are: %s", compositeKeyParts[0], compositeKeyParts[1], compositeKeyParts[2])

        permissionAsBytes, err := ctx.GetStub().GetState(permissionId)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten == true {
            newBytes := append([]byte(","), permissionAsBytes...)
            permissions = append(permissions, newBytes...)
        } else {
            permissions = append(permissions, permissionAsBytes...)
            fmt.Print(permissions)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Found a asset for index : %s asset id : ", objectType, compositeKeyParts[0], compositeKeyParts[1], compositeKeyParts[2])
        bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten = true

    }

    permissions = append(permissions, []byte("]")...)
    fmt.Print(permissions)
    return permissions, nil
}
```

Comment: I'm suspecting that the permissions variable `permissions []byte` is not the right type which I declare to be returned. But that doesn't make sense because I declared them both to be a slice of bytes `[]byte`. My second gues would be that the input of the slice is just a string and not the permission object which results in an error. But I don't have much experience in golang so I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is a link to the [full chaincode file](https://github.com/JonasHiltl/EHR) on github

Answer (score 3):

I have had a run of the code supplied above and you are correct in your comment that the issue appears to stem from the use of `[]byte` as your return type. I'm not entirely sure why this happened as that should be a valid return type. I will look further into this as it may be a bug.

I was able to get the data returned correctly by converting the return type to `string` and returning `string(permissions)`

I noticed whilst doing that, that your code is building a byte array based on the getState bytes. Therefore another option is to `json.Unmarshal` the bytes from the get state call into a `Permission` struct and append this to an array. You can then have the return type as `[]Permission`.

I would recomend for now you take either the string or Permission array approach as I will have to look into what is happening with using `[]byte` as a return type.

## Examples:

### string:

```
// List all Permissions given to a doctor
func (s *SmartContract) ListDoctorPermissions(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, doctorId string) (string, error) {
    doctorIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetStateByPartialCompositeKey("permissionId", []string{doctorId})
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    fmt.Printf("the doctor Iterator is: %s", doctorIterator)

    defer doctorIterator.Close()

    var dataCategory string
    var patientId string
    var permissionId string

    var permissions []byte
    bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten := false

    for doctorIterator.HasNext() {
        responseRange, err := doctorIterator.Next()
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        objectType, compositeKeyParts, err := ctx.GetStub().SplitCompositeKey(responseRange.Key)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        fmt.Printf("the objectType is: %s", objectType)

        dataCategory = compositeKeyParts[1]
        patientId = compositeKeyParts[2]
        permissionId = doctorId + dataCategory + patientId
        fmt.Printf("the compositeKeyParts are: %s", compositeKeyParts[0], compositeKeyParts[1], compositeKeyParts[2])

        permissionAsBytes, err := ctx.GetStub().GetState(permissionId)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        if bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten == true {
            newBytes := append([]byte(","), permissionAsBytes...)
            permissions = append(permissions, newBytes...)
        } else {
            permissions = append(permissions, permissionAsBytes...)
            fmt.Print(permissions)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Found a asset for index : %s asset id : ", objectType, compositeKeyParts[0], compositeKeyParts[1], compositeKeyParts[2])
        bArrayPermissionAlreadyWritten = true

    }

    permissions = append(permissions, []byte("]")...)
    fmt.Print(permissions)
    return string(permissions), nil
}
```

### []Permission:

```
// List all Permissions given to a doctor
func (s *SmartContract) ListDoctorPermissions(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, doctorId string) ([]Permission, error) {
    doctorIterator, err := ctx.GetStub().GetStateByPartialCompositeKey("permissionId", []string{doctorId})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("the doctor Iterator is: %s", doctorIterator)

    defer doctorIterator.Close()

    var dataCategory string
    var patientId string
    var permissionId string

    var permissions []Permission

    for doctorIterator.HasNext() {
        responseRange, err := doctorIterator.Next()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        objectType, compositeKeyParts, err := ctx.GetStub().SplitCompositeKey(responseRange.Key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        fmt.Printf("the objectType is: %s", objectType)

        dataCategory = compositeKeyParts[1]
        patientId = compositeKeyParts[2]
        permissionId = doctorId + dataCategory + patientId
        fmt.Printf("the compositeKeyParts are: %s", compositeKeyParts[0], compositeKeyParts[1], compositeKeyParts[2])

        permissionAsBytes, err := ctx.GetStub().GetState(permissionId)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        foundPermission := new(Permission)

        err = json.Unmarshal(permissionAsBytes, foundPermission)

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        permissions = append(permissions, *foundPermission)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Permissions %v", permissions)

    return permissions, nil
}
```