# How can I use UUID (as byte array) in Hyperledger Fabric chaincode written in Go?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, uuid, hyperledger-chaincode

I am writing chaincode in Go for Hyperledger Fabric. I have next code

```
package chaincode

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"
)

type SmartContract struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

type MyStruct struct {
    ID         string 
    Description string `json:"description"`
    UUID   uuid.UUID `json:"uuid"`
}

func (s *SmartContract) Create(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, ID string, description string) error {
    asset := MyStruct{
        ID:         ID,
        Description: description,
        UUID:     uuid.Nil,
    }
    js, err := json.Marshal(asset)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return ctx.GetStub().PutState(asset.ID,js)
}

func (s *SmartContract) Get(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, ID string) (*MyStruct, error) {
    assetAsBytes, err := ctx.GetStub().GetState(ID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read from world state: %w", err)
    }

    if assetAsBytes == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s does not exist", ID)
    }

    asset := new(MyStruct)
    err = json.Unmarshal(assetAsBytes, asset)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("can not unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    return asset, nil
}
```

Before I had same code, but without UUID field and it worked well. But now, after adding this field, I am getting next error `Value did not match schema:\n1. return.uuid: Invalid type. Expected: array, given: string"`  when I call `Get` method.

But as I can see, writing to and reading from ledger works well, but there is some error in peer and chaincode communication. I can't understand, how to fix this error, except replacing UUID field with string type.

Is there any way to fix it without replacing type? I want to use UUID as  uuid.UUID ( byte array), not as string, because I don't want to make conversions and UUID string validation.

Comment: I checked code, and note, that problem not exactly with UUID, but with byte array.

Answer (score 1):

a similar issue has been faced in this question:

[Hyperledger error when trying to query the state database after installing the chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993532/hyperledger-error-when-trying-to-query-the-state-database-after-installing-the-c/66100010#66100010)

Currently the advice is to convert to a string as the contract API seems to be mishandling byte arrays. This is something that should be fixed in the future but a definitive timeline it not known.